# Promote "comparison between pointer and integer" from warning to error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode. I have the "classic" `comparison between pointer and integer` warning. It's clear to me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it.

I want to transform this warning into a full error as I did for example changing from

```
-Wincomplete-implementation
```

to

```
-Werror=incomplete-implementation
```

However when showing me that diagnostic (using `Reveal in Log` command), Xcode does not give any other information on the specific warning code. Does anybody know what is the code for this warning? (and no, I do not want to treat all warning as errors, it's not my goal)

Comment: You can right-click the error in the Issue Navigator and select Reveal in Log. You should be able to see the name of the warning there.

Comment: This is the problem. There is no code there. Going to edit.

Comment: Thanks @MichałCiuba, I was looking for this kind of list of warnings.